# How can i have a dynamic .addmethod for jQuery Unobtrusive validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am currently using jQuery unobtrusive validation together with ASP.NET MVC.

I have set up my backend code in such a way that it is possible to send more than one regex validation  to a given input field, resulting in something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-alphanumericonly="This field can only contain alphanumerical characters." data-val-alphanumericonly-pattern="^[a-z0-9àâäçéèêëïöôûü\s]+$" data-val-nospaces="This field can't contain spaces." data-val-nospaces-pattern="^\S+$" id="User_UserName" name="User.UserName" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="">
```

I can now make this work perfectly by adding the following code in the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file

```
$jQval.addMethod("nospaces", function (value, element, params) {
    var match;
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);
    return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
});
adapters.addSingleVal("nospaces", "pattern");
$jQval.addMethod("alphanumericonly", function (value, element, params) {
    var match;
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);
    return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
});
adapters.addSingleVal("alphanumericonly", "pattern");
```

My only problem is that i don't want to do this for each rule seperatly, since its the exact same code every time. I would like to know if there is a way to do this in a dynamic way.

I was thinking about using a prefix and then having the same method once, responding on the prefix instead of the entire name.
So having regex_nospaces and regex_alphanumericalonly and having the functions as $jQval.addMethod("regex_*", ...

PS: I already tried by using the same name, but i have to specify unique names for .Net

Comment: `.addMethod()` absolutely does not get repeated for every field.  `.addMethod()` simply creates a new rule that can be used on as many fields as you wish.

Comment: yes, but i would like to use this new rule multiple times on the same field. Since I can't use the same name due to what i'm sending from serverside, i am forced to add a new rule for each named rule.
Since all the logic is server side, adding a rule is the same each time, so I want to make this more DRY.

Comment: *"i would like to use this new rule multiple times on the same field."* ~ How would you use the same rule on the same field multiple times?  That really does not make any sense.  Example: if the "foobar" field is supposed to be "required", then the `required` rule is added to the `foobar` field ONE time, then this field will always be "required".

Comment: It's only for adding regex queries, in many cases I want to add multiple regex rules to one field. 
This entire setup is working perfectly and as it should be. The only thing I want to do is not repeat the same function to let jquery validate know it should do a regex.

Comment: If that's all you want, then include the `additional-methods.js` file and use the built-in `pattern` (regex) rule.   The actual regex is passed into the rule as a parameter.

Comment: The code i'm using (see above) is (slightly modified) the pattern rule. The problem is that i can't use pattern more than once on the same field due to what i'm sending from serverside to create this. So what I'm looking for is a way to use this function, but making the parameter of the name of the rule (in your case "pattern") dynamic. It needs to check if the name starts with regex_ or something and then apply.